# how to get rid of a warning that Attempt to present Controller on UITabBarController while a presentation is in progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a controller i.e `MediaViewController` that is on `UITabBarController` defined in `AppDelegate`. I present a `NewCameraViewController` over this `MediaViewController`, then on this `NewCameraViewController` I present an image picker.after selecting an image from this picker I dismiss this picker. But now when I dismiss this `NewCameraViewController` then I'm getting this warning

> "Attempt to present Controller on `UITabBarController` while a presentation is in progress!"

I'm not getting the reason behind this warning and as so solution of this warning.

Comment: where you are dismissing the view, can you add that part of code?

Comment: the url of method is http://pastie.org/9404632

Comment: can you show viewWillAppear of MediaViewController?